# Is a person warmed by fire an example of endothermic reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry

My chemistry textbook gives the example of a man being warmed by a fire as an endothermic reaction. If the man's body is the system and it is increasing in temperature, how can this be endothermic?

Comment: It's endothermic because the man is taking in heat, hence why he's increasing in temperature. Exothermic systems release energy (the fire), endothermic systems absorb energy (the man).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it an endothermic chemical reaction. The fire is an example of an exothermic reaction. The man constitutes part of the surroundings for the fire (the system), and heat is being transferred between the system and its surroundings. Looking at it the opposite way, the fire could be considered the surroundings (a heat reservoir) for the man (the system), and there is heat being transferred from the surroundings to the system. But the man is not undergoing a chemical reaction.